# React js and Spring boot URL Parameters

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, axios, react-router-v4

Hello i need to get `id` in my parameter and i get error

this is my code :

```
<td>  <Link to="/updateregion/${listregion.id}"></Link>  </td>
```

what i  should to do please

and this is the  code for navigation :

```
<Route path="/updateregion/:id" component={updateregion}/>
```

Comment: where is the code for getting the id ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
// updaterection.jsx
import React from 'react'

const updateregion = props => {
  const id = props.match.params.id
  // return JSX
}

export default updateregion
```

Comment: nn i need to send id in updateregion {listeregion.id}